# How to completely separate layouts for different customer groups

Tags: magento-1.9

We are building a store in which it is required to make totally different account dashboards for various customer groups.

So, for my humble experience, I have two options, to filter on the controller level (to make checks in the AccountController for example and pass vars to block), and to filter (add/remove layout handles) it via observer (according to this link http://www.atwix.com/magento/magento-customer-group-layout-handle/).

I decide to do it via observer, but client worrying if some difficulties may occur in future (adding/removing lots of layout handles), in case dashboard for certain user group will grow, and asks me to separate the logic "on the root".

Thinking on how to do it and would love to hear some expert's advice on how to plan architecture for this purpose, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it heavily depends upon *what* exactly you need to change about the customer experience. Assuming layout modifications (see below), handling it by adding a customer group layout handle using the observer method you outlined in your link above is a good approach.

Your controller idea is much more tedious as it will either limit your modifications to routes handled by that single controller or you'd have to override several controllers should you need to modify other pages.

By contrast, the layout handle method will allow you to do all kinds of stuff on a customer group basis such as:

- Add Blocks
- Remove Blocks
- Add Styles/Scripts
- Change the template files used by a particular blocks...